# Fatal Error Encountered using LINQ and mysqlconnection

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, fatal-error

I'm quite new to c# so please any help would be great. I made a simple console code to update to mysql database, rest assured my database is done setting up, App.config is done. Now, the problem is when I run to test my code this error occurred. "Fatal error encountered during command execution"

below is my code:

class library:

```
public class DBEntity
{
        private MySqlConnection DBConnection { get;  set; }
        public string INSERT = "insert";
        public string SELECT = "select";
        public string UPDATE = "update";

        public void Get_Connection(string ConnectionString)
        {
            DBConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        }

        public void Close_Connection()
        {
            DBConnection.Close();
        }

        public void Query(string operation, string query, params object[] values)
        {
            try
            {
                DBConnection.Open();
                switch (operation)
                {
                    case "update":
                        try
                        {
                            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DBConnection))
                            {
                                IEnumerable<string> tokens = query.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\'', ';', ',' }).Where(str => str.Contains('@'));
                                var zipTwoTokens = tokens.Zip(values, (token, vals) => cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(token, vals)).ToList();

                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                DBConnection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (MySqlException e)
                        {
                            DBConnection.Close();
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException)
            {

            }
       }
}
```

The Main class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DBEntity database = new DBEntity();
        database.Get_Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnection"].ConnectionString);
        database.Query(database.UPDATE, "UPDATE RoyDB.Products SET Products.Name = @productName WHERE Products.ProductID = @product;", "Kayak", 1);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when I run to test my code this error occurred. "Fatal error encountered during command execution"

can anyone help me? I dont seem to get the cause of the error.

any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you split the query up to determine the parameters is not quite correct. In this case it is including the semicolon so you get parameters called `@productName` and `@product;`. Add in semicolon to the split string like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> tokens = 
    query.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\'', ';'}).Where(str => str.Contains('@'));
```

Additionally, you need to actually force the `Zip` method to be called as Linq uses deferred execution. To to this, add `ToList` on the end of the zip:

```
var zipTwoTokens = 
    parameterToken.Zip(values, (prmtoken, vals) => 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(prmtoken, vals)).ToList();
```

Comment: I've tried it but the code still wont work. when I check the locals, 
the parameter count is still 0 though zip has been applied before ExecuteNonQuery method

Comment: Thanks I've it worked! :D
Is there any link to know about what you called "Deferred Execution"?
I cant seem to get it. 

I've edited the code, can you check it out?